# How to format menu entries for your Enterprise Architect add-in?

Tags: c#, add-in, enterprise-architect

I'm working on an Enterprise Architect add-in and recently added shortcut support.
I display the registered shortcut key combination in the add-ins (treeview) right click menu. Is there any possibility of formatting these Menu entries? I want to "flush right" the shortcut annotation just like EA is doing themselves in for example "properties" menu.

Probably even not a simple Flush right, as all EA shortcut annotations begin at the same width, but are flushed right as a group.

I cannot find any documentation on any formatting.
The Menu entrys are given as simple array, where each entry is a new menu entry.
I tried html and css tags and also "\t" does not work.
"\t" makes anything after it disappear for some reason, so there might be some sort of formatting. "\t" will be printed out though as "\t".

I wrote a "hack" where spaces are inserted depending on preceding character count, but as the font is not Monospace, that also doesn't align my shortcut annotations.

Any ideas?

(In case somebody stumbles across here in hope of adding his own shortcut support, this works:
https://community.sparxsystems.com/tutorials/1181-using-keyboard-shortcuts-with-enterprise-architect-extension-menus)

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Even if you add tabs to your menu entry text, it would not automatically align right

Comment: I'd guess that Windoze has two columns for menus. One for the name, one for the shortcut. And EA puts your text always in the name column. You need to ask for a new feature. Good luck with that.